# How to enale url enctryption on Grafana portal while diplaying dasbhboard

Tags: url, encryption, grafana, influxdb, grafana-api

I want to enable url encryption on grafana in-house portal. When we design any sample payload with lets say influxDb/Mysql as database. On defined interval dashboard data will get refreshed by calling rest call to server in backend mode, while making call to server they have query parameter having sql query which designed for dashboard. Anyone on network payload easily can  grab the sql details.

I want to make those rest call to secure or may be encrypted. Do we have any configuration on grafana.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you change the datasource options to use the POST method instead of GET, that the contents of your query will be inside the body of the request and thus protected by SSL.
[Datasource Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhWox.png)

Comment: Actually, the query string should be protected by SSL as well. Were you worried about your grafana users seeing the query or unauthenticated eavesdroppers?

Comment: Yes thats correct. End logged-in user can view the complete sql query from developer tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the grafana users seeing the query, and not just eavesdroppers on the network, then you could potentially make use of the ability to serve on demand rendered images of panels. See the following:

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/share_panel/